codecentric cxf spring boot starter plugin with jdk17
I'm migrating a spring boot service from version 2.x.x and java 8 to spring boot v3.3.1 and java 17.
The main problem is that the cxf-spring-boot-starter-maven-plugin generates deprecated javax imports instead of the new jakarta imports. How do i configure the plugin to generate java 17 compatible java files.
This is what my pom looks like:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xxx-Service</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>REST- und SOAP-Schnittstelle zum xxx</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <jadice.legacy.version>4.3.0.26</jadice.legacy.version>
        <log4j.version>2.17.1</log4j.version>
        <cxf.version>3.5.5</cxf.version>
        <jakarta.xml.bind-api.version>4.0.2</jakarta.xml.bind-api.version>
        <jakarta.jms-api.version>3.1.0</jakarta.jms-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            ...

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        ...

        <!-- SOAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.xml.bind-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.xml.bind-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Generate package Name of SEI and WebServiceClient for later Autodetection of Endpoints in cxf-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
       

        <!-- SOAP-Webservice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1-jaxb-jaxws-3.0.0-M4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            ...

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

The documentation of the plugin states that it's possible, but it isn't specified how to configure it to generate the right imports.
